# ASP.NET - evaluating button value from code behind

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I've got an asp button which is calling a C# method when the user clicks on it :

```
<asp:Button id="btnReport2" name="btnReport2"  runat="server" Text="Show Report" ToolTip="Report" OnClick="btnReport2_Click"/>
```

The following method is called :

```
 protected void btnReport2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (btnReport2.Text == "Show Report")
            {
                GetReport();

            }

            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "ShowReport", "ShowReport()", true);
    }
```

As you can see, at the end of the method, I'm calling a jQuery script :

```
function ShowReport() {
            debugger;
            if ($('#btnReport2').val() == 'Show Report') {
                $('#btnReport2').val('Hide Report');
                $('#spPrint').attr('style', 'display:inline');
                $('#btnDeleteAll2').animate({ width: ['toggle', 'swing'], heigth: ['toggle', 'swing'], opacity: 'toggle' }, 500, "swing");
                $('#divReport').animate({ width: ['toggle', 'swing'], heigth: ['toggle', 'swing'], opacity: 'toggle' }, 500, "swing");
                $('#divResult').slideToggle(500);
            } else {
                $('#btnReport2').val('Show Report');
                $('#spPrint').attr('style', 'display:none');

            }

        }
```

When the button is clicked, I change its text to "Hide report". However, when I'm clicking on it again, while debugging, the btnReport2.Text property is still set to "Show report" which is strange for me because it displays "Hide report".

Any idea about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You have changed the value of button only on client side not on server side. That's why value still remains same while debugging on server side.

Comment: That's what I'm doing. I'm just evaluating the value on server side.

Comment: To change the value on server side change value of property btnReport2.Text.